# facebook like callback problem on opera

Tags: facebook, callback, facebook-like, opera

```
 FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create', function(href, widget) {
 alert('You just liked '+href);
 });
```

This function doesn't work on opera i didn't find any solution. Are there any fix for this ?

these are opera problems

```
JavaScript - http://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?channel_url=http%3A%2F%2Fstatic.ak.fbcdn.net%2Fconnect%2Fxd_proxy.php%3Fversion%3D0%23cb%3Df16279b054d7fb%26origin%3Dhttp%253A%252F%252Fdeneme.com%252Ff1f6bfa5892b7f%26relation%3Dparent.parent%26transport%3Dflash&href=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.deneme.com&layout=standard&locale=en_US&node_type=link&sdk=joey&show_faces=false&width=450
Timeout thread: delay 3000 ms
Uncaught exception: TypeError: Cannot convert 'c.parentNode' to object
Error thrown at line 12, column 1919 in <anonymous function>() in http://b.static.ak.fbcdn.net/rsrc.php/v1/yq/r/FmJU1Ria9Bd.js:
    c.parentNode.removeChild(c);
```

Answer (score 0):

I work for Opera and we'll push out a workaround against some problems with Facebook Connect shortly. Could you try again in a week or so?

The update will be announced on http://my.opera.com/sitepatching/blog/ and you don't need to upgrade Opera itself - it will happen automatically if the browser.js feature is enabled. See http://www.opera.com/docs/browserjs/

Answer (score 0):

It's august '11 and it seems the problem still exists. Any workaround someone?
**Update:** After a hack I did for Safari it suddenly works in Opera as well. My hack was taken from:
http://anantgarg.com/2010/02/18/cross-domain-cookies-in-safari/